# Geonames API add new name

Tags: api, rdf, geonames

I started to integrate Geonames in my RDF. I use the web services to search informations about places, but the browsers gui to add new names. There is a way to send the lat,lng coordinates and create a new name automatically?

EDIT:
I have some kml files. I want to use the coordinates value to create new elements in geonames (http://www.geonames.org). I have to do this "manually", going on the map and giving a "insert new name here" command.
To read information from geonames there are some web services (http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html), but I didn't found nothing for insert new elements.

Comment: There's not enough information here to diagnose this problem.  Can you provide a more detail about what you're doing and what you've tried.  Explain it to us as though we've used Geonames browser GUI.  Point us to the website you're using, and the exact input you're providing.

Comment: I edited the post. I hope is clearer.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.  I wouldn't be surprised if it's not an API accessible to the public.  It'd be very easy to abuse… (That's not an answer to this question, though.)

Comment: Also not an answer, but perhaps of interest to anyone else who finds this, the documentation for creating places is [Add a new placename to the GeoNames database](http://www.geonames.org/manual.html#create).  (It also mentions, "You have to be logged in to add a place name. This restriction helps to prevent vandalism.")

Comment: I had saw the documentation, but I didn't think that it could be "to prevent vandalism"... Thanks anyway...